# Is there a way to center a stencil map in the 3D View?

Tags: vertex-paint

Vertex Paint mode, Texture painting with Stencil Map.

The map gets created down left in the 3D View. And clicking at the Reset Transform button resets the stencil map back to down left. But i would need it in the middle. The more exact the better. I cannot center the 3d objects down left. They also center in the middle.

Is there a way to center the stencil map in the 3D view?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I've tried many times before w/o success...I starred and up voted your question though.

Comment: To center exactly ? You can move it by clicking `RMB` (just like in Texture Painting), however this would be approximation. I am not aware of any automated way.

Comment: Yes, to center exactly. I thought there is a way to calculate everything together and to create a script for it.